# Select2 make select from html elements

Tags: html, select

Hello I have html structure:

```
<div class="main">
    <span data-value="option1_value">option1</span>
    <span data-value="option2_value">option2</span>
    ...
</div>
```

How can I make a select form with "Select2 jquery" ?

**UPDATE**

Finaly made it myself, maybe it will helps to someone ;)

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $list   = $(".main"),
        $select = $('<select class="yourclass" />');

    $list.children('span').each(function(index) {
        $select.append($('<option />').attr('value', $(this).attr('data-value')).html($(this).html()));
    });
    $list.replaceWith($select);

    $(".yourclass").select2({
        placeholder: "Select"
        });
    });
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried so far to get any help ;-)

Comment: will it be easier for you ? :) $(".main").select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
            placeholder: "Select"
        });

Answer (score 0):

You may change HTML structure to something like

```
<select id="simple_select" class="main" >
    <!-- declaring options in HTML is not mandatory if you use other source of data -->
    <option value="value_to_send_#1">Display to user #1</option>    
    <option value="value_to_send_#2">Display to user #2</option>
    <option value="value_to_send_#3">Display to user #3</option>
</select>
```

And in the script call jQuery select method like this:

```
var input = $("#simple_select")
    .select2({
        //--options--//
    });
```

Assuming you have Select2 (js,CSS) libraries loaded.

Comment: The problem is that I cant edit this part of code, so I need to figure this out how to make a select form ...

Comment: Okay, I now see the clue :D You gonna have a little hard time but you might do some workaround and scrap text and attributes from each span to get everything in array like  [{ id:"value", text:"option to show"}, ...] and pass it to select2 data option to prevent from generating HTML structure twice. I see You arleady got the other solution :)